# Deriving BJT transistor equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering

Is it possible to derive the behavior of BJT transistors using semiconductor physics?

I have seen a derivation of PN junction behavior using some assumptions which was plausible to me but I had a curiosity to look back again and the BJT derivation had some pretty big jumps. Basically it was never explained where current amplification really came from, how its equation would be derived or why the electrons didn't all exit the base vs traveling through the P doped material to enter the collector.

Comment: Well, Sze does pretty well in "The Physics of Semiconductor Devices", as do other authors.

Comment: Millman, "Electronic devices and circuits", Street man, "Solid state electronic devices", Sze, "Physics of semiconductor devices", Muller Kamins, "Device electronics for integrated circuits" 2e

Comment: As for your last question, the carriers that the emitter injects into base become minority carriers there and behave like a gas: they diffuse irregardless of the electric field and, due to the geometry of the base the vast majority end up being scooped up by the collector. (Oh and it's Streetman),

Comment: Make sure you fully understand the operation of a pn-junction first, specifically what's called the "law of the junction": the boundary conditions around the depletion region. Get comfortable drawing band diagrams of the junction under bias (with the quasi-Fermi levels). Pierret's "Semiconductor Device Fundamentals" might also be helpful.

Comment: Injection of minority carriers into the base modulates the majority carrier population in the base. This reduction in majority carriers increases the lifetime (and hence diffusion length) for minority carriers, so that carriers injected from the emitter can now make it across to the collector. Without the lifetime modulation, minority carriers don't make it across the base so there is no collector current. So, a small base current leads to a very large emitter-to-collector current being possible, which is amplification.

Comment: @JonCuster Why would minority carrier injection into the base reduce the majority carrier density?

Comment: @Puk - because in equilibrium $np = n_{i}^{2}$, so injecting one will change the other through recombination.

Comment: @JonCuster The base is not in equilibrium when the BJT is under bias, so the law of mass action doesn't apply. For low level injection, the majority carrier density is just the doping density. For high level injection, the majority carrier density can actually *increase* with minority carrier injection, but I don't know if this is common with BJTs.

Comment: It may not get to equilibrium, but it sure modulates the majority carrier concentration, which modulates the minority carrier lifetime, which enables the minority carriers to transit the base. Sze is explicit about all that. That little bit of base injection results in minority carrier densities that are 10,000 times larger or so than equilibrium without injection.

Comment: @JonCuster Could you state where he says that the minority carrier injection modulates the base majority carrier concentration in any meaningful way, or increases the minority carrier lifetime or diffusion length in the base?

Comment: Can the gain be derived analytically though? My big issue is while there might be a qualitative discussion here it's not actually coming from the theory - they are basically just assumptions being made or a give constant.